# TopMost form in a thread?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, forms, topmost

I am using the following code to open a form in a new thread:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Thread thread = new Thread(ThreadProc);
    thread.Start();
}


public void ThreadProc()
{

    Form form = new Form();
    form.TopMost = true;
    form.ShowDialog();
}
```

But the newly created form isn't TopMost even though I set it to true.

How can I make a form in a thread TopMost ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually you don't need another thread, you open the form as usual in modal or non modal mode, if the form needs to do a heavy process then you do the process inside a thread.

Specific to your question one option is to run the form from an Application.Run as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167323/how-to-open-a-form-in-a-thread-and-force-it-to-stay-open/167377#167377).

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(ThreadProc);
        thread.Start();
    }


    public void ThreadProc()
    {
        using (Form1 _form = new Form1())
        {
            _form.TopMost = true;
            Application.Run(_form);
        }
    }
}
```

That will launch a new thread with its own message pump and will keep it as a TopMost form.

Comment: Ok so that should create a form in a new thread and allow it to become topmost form? I will give it a try ! thx

Comment: That actually didnt work because if i "Application.Run(_form);" in the new thread it stills is in a new thread and the problem will remain that it wont become topmost, and if i try to start "Application.Run(_form);" without starting a new thread(starting in the main thread) then i get exception " Starting a second message loop on a single thread is not a valid operation."

Comment: I modified with a more complete code, it produces the expected result for me

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into this problem myself. It seems that if the form has an [`Owner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.owner.aspx), then `TopMost` works as expected. If the owning form was created on another thread, though, it's a little [tricky to set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273674/cross-thread-exception-when-setting-winforms-form-owner-how-to-do-it-right/5274683#5274683). Here's what I used:

```
var form = new Form();

form.Shown += (sender, e) => {
    Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
    form.Owner = /* Owning form here */;
    form.CenterToParent();      // Not necessary
    Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = true;

    form.TopMost = true;        // Works now!
};

Application.Run(form);
```

Comment: You just saved the day.  Thanks so much :D :D

Answer (score -1):

Instead of calling ShowDialog directly, try using this.Invoke to gain ownership of the form.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Thread thread = new Thread(ThreadProc);
    thread.Start();
}


public void ThreadProc()
{

    Form form = new Form();
    form.TopMost = true;
    this.Invoke((Action)delegate() { form.ShowDialog(); });
}
```

Comment: As is your answer is rather uninformative.  Consider adding ***why*** this might be the solution.