# Ticker generated forms not displaying correctly

Tags: c#, forms, prompt, ticker

Hopefully this isn't too difficult to follow.

I'm currently working on a small timelogging application that runs quietly in the background. Every time the ticker runs down, the application prompts the user to say what he/she was doing since the last prompt. I'll eventually have the application write the data into a spreadsheet.

One of the options I have so far enables the user to choose whether or not he/she would like to use the default prompting setting (every time a prompt is missed, it stays visible until the next one is created, meaning if the user leaves his/her computer for a while there may be a fair few prompts sitting on the screen waiting to be filled in) or would like to combine all the prompts (every time a prompt is missed and a new one pops up, the old one is closed and the new one covers the time of the old prompt and the new prompt).

The user can also select a tickbox to turn prompts off. When he/she turns prompts back on again, a prompt pops up asking the user to fill in what he/she was doing while prompts were turned off (useful when the user is running fullscreen applications, etc).

My problem is, when I try to generate the prompts, they don't display correctly. I can't manipulate them at all and none of the controls display. They basically look like empty forms.

Here's my code for generating prompts using the ticker:

```
public void ticker(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (groupMissed)
        {
            incrementsMissed += 1;
            if (incrementsMissed > 1)
            {
                IncrementForm form = (IncrementForm)Application.OpenForms["IncrementForm"];
                if (form.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    form.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { form.Close(); }));
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            incrementsMissed = 1;
        }

        IncrementForm theIncrementForm = new IncrementForm(this, e.SignalTime);
        theIncrementForm.Show();
        latestIncrement = e.SignalTime;
    }
```

And here's my code for generating prompts using the "turn prompts off" checkbox:

```
private void chkbxAlerts_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!chkbxAlerts.Checked)
        {
            // Ensures that the time missed is covered and restarts the timer
            DateTime now;
            now = DateTime.Now;
            if ((now - latestIncrement).TotalMinutes >= 1) // Only records time if it is equal to or greater than one minute
            {
                // TO-DO: FIX
                if (groupMissed)
                {
                    incrementsMissed += 1;
                    if (incrementsMissed > 1)
                    {
                        IncrementForm form = (IncrementForm)Application.OpenForms["IncrementForm"];
                        if (form.InvokeRequired)
                        {
                            form.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { form.Close(); }));
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    incrementsMissed = 1;
                }
                IncrementForm theIncrementForm = new IncrementForm(this, now, latestIncrement);
                theIncrementForm.Show();
                latestIncrement = now;
            }
            timer.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // Stops the timer
            timer.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

If you need any further clarification, please let me know. Thanks so much in advance for any help, this has been bugging me.

Comment: a very well formed question - though still some things missing. Is your ticker a timer-driven? timer is calling from another thread - You cannot update GUI form from in there (though you can show / spawn forms in different threads - not sure what might end up 'giving' in your case)...yes, that's another thread sure

Comment: Yes, the ticker is called by the Elapsed event on a timer. How can I get around this GUI problem you mention?

Comment: could you craft a small 'runnable' example? there's more to this I'm guessing

Comment: @NSGaga I just did a quick bit of research and realised that the problem is indeed because I am trying to perform UI functions within the timer thread, like you said. I just need to figure out how to thread said functions through the UI thread. This is confusing stuff.

Comment: do you have a main window running at all times?

Comment: That's correct, it runs in the taskbar. It contains my timer code and all the code you see above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Timers.Timer` has a [SynchronizingObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject.aspx) property. If you set that to the main form (or the form that contains the timer), then the timer tick event will be raised on the GUI thread.

Do note that `System.Timers.Timer` has the nasty habit of swallowing exceptions that occur in the `Elapsed` event. If your tick handler throws an exception, you'll never see it. It's a nasty bug hider. For that reason, I recommend using either `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` or `System.Threading.Timer`. If you use the Windows Forms timer, the elapsed event is raised on the GUI thread. If you use `System.Threading.Timer`, you'll have to use `Invoke` as NSGaga shows in his answer.

See [Swallowing exceptions is hiding bugs](http://blog.mischel.com/2011/05/19/swallowing-exceptions-is-hiding-bugs/) for more information about why I discourage the use of `System.Timers.Timer`.

Comment: Your solution works well, thanks! Just one thing. System.Windows.Forms.Timer doesn't seem to have an equivalent to System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs.SignalTime so I just used DateTime.Now instead. Thought you might want to know if you didn't already.

Answer (score 2):

I think, from what I can see, not 100% but your timer is spawning your windows in a separate thread (being from the timer ticker call).

While theoretically that can work (take a look at this [How to open a form in a thread and force it to stay open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167323/how-to-open-a-form-in-a-thread-and-force-it-to-stay-open))
...you may be much better off staying within the main thread.

Try something like this...

```
yourMainWindow.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
    {
        IncrementForm theIncrementForm = new IncrementForm(this, e.SignalTime);
        theIncrementForm.Show();
        latestIncrement = e.SignalTime;
    }));
```

...that's from your timer - that way (as I can see) you should have it all 'on the main thread' and make things much easier for you.

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! Even though I didn't end up using your approach, you really helped me understand threading more. So thanks again!