# The desktop application project I developed using C # cannot open the file selection window using OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, winforms

```
namespace WinFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;

        #region
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            timer.Interval = 6000; 
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerTickHandler); 
            
            timer.Start();
        }
       
        private void TimerTickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            timer.Dispose();
       
            Thread t1 = new Thread(delegate () { new Form2().ShowDialog(); });

            t1.Start();
            //Close();
           
            Dispose();
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

This code shown above redirects me from `form1` (which I set as the startup page) to `form2`.

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
ofd.InitialDirectory = Application.StartupPath;
ofd.Title = "";
ofd.Multiselect = false;
ofd.Filter = "PDF| *.pdf|all |*.* ";
ofd.FilterIndex = 1; 
ofd.RestoreDirectory = true;

if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string selectedFile = ofd.FileName;
}
```

In `Form2`, I added a button control that called the above code to open the file selection window, but when clicked, the window did not pop up and the application froze

There is some additional information: If I open free2 in free1 (startup page) without closing free1 through code, the file selection window can pop up normally, but in this case, the startup page will always exist.

May I ask what I should do to make Form1 (start page) open and close Form2, so that the file selection window event in Form2 can be triggered normally? Please provide specific code examples

Comment: Please pay close attention when selecting tags. Don't just type one letter and `Enter`, that will likely select the wrong tag. Like you did when selecting the C language tag instead of C#.

Comment: Fixed tag: c -> c#.

Comment: Please see this link for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167323/how-to-open-a-form-in-a-thread-and-force-it-to-stay-open

Comment: This: `new Form2().ShowDialog()` won't work in a background thread, it must run on UI thread.

Comment: You don't need any secondary Thread for this -- If you close (or dispose, same thing) your starting Form, the application closes -- If you don't want to see the starting Form, for some reason, then hide it

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a new application if you want to close the main Form.
if you close the main application every thing will close.
This way the form2 will run independently. And Form1 can be closed.

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(delegate () { Application.Run( new Form2()); });
```

Better approach can be found here: [Applicationcontext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext?view=windowsdesktop-8.0)